# xsl:value-of vs xsl:apply-templates: what is faster?

Tags: xslt

Looking at all the examples of XSL, I've noticed that
some people use xsl:value-of  while others use apply-templates.  Which method is faster than the another and why?

Comment: Such choice is limited to parents of text nodes only. You would have to conduct a comparison using your specific processor, but I suspect the difference, if any, will be negligible.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, they don't do the same thing, so it's not a simple choice based on performance.

Secondly, you can't ask questions about the performance of language constructs except in the context of a specific processor. There are a dozen popular XSLT processors and another dozen that are less well known, and they all perform differently.

Thirdly, if anyone tells you that one is faster than the other, they probably won't tell you all the configuration variables that you need to reproduce their measurements, and if they do, your own circumstances will probably be quite different.

So the best thing to do is to measure it and see, and tell us what results you obtained.